# Repetitive pattern but the last one is different - Regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have this pattern:

`^([a-zA-Z0-9]+ )+$`

It is supposed to match sentences like:

```
sfjgsjsg_sbskdf_dsjkfshfsh
sdfhs_skjhsijdgh_dsnjbkg_sdkfsbk_nasjksdj_nsdjkfs
```

I don't know the word size nor how many words will be in each line.

The problem is that upper pattern identify only sentences like:

```
sfjgsjsg_sbskdf_dsjkfshfsh_
sdfhs_skjhsijdgh_dsnjbkg_sdkfsbk_nasjksdj_nsdjkfs_
```

Being `_`->`(space)`

Comment: Use `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

Or, if any whitespace is meant:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

If there can be only one occurrence of horizontal spaces:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[\p{Zs}\t][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

and if there can be more than one:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[\p{Zs}\t]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

Note that leading/trailing whitespace support can be added by placing  `*`, `[\p{Zs}\t]`or `\s*` next to the `^` (right after it) and `$` (right before it) anchors.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - one or more ASCII alphanumeric chars
- - a space (`[\p{Zs}\t]` is any whitespace other than line break chars, `\s` matches any whitespaces)
- `(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of a space and one or more ASCII alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.